# Use reactive extension to pair request and response

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive

**Scenario:**

I send request to server queue (I'm using RabbintMQ to asynchronously process message). When the server processes the request it produces two responses to different queues.

I would like to use RX to subscribe to to responses, but also have access to their corresponding requests.

**What I have so far:**

I use EventAggregator that uses reactive extension and exposes IObservable for event stream:

```
public interface IEventAggregator
{
    void Publish<TEvent>(TEvent sampleEvent);
    IObservable<TEvent> GetEvent<TEvent>();
}
```

When I send request I publish an event:

```
eventAggregator.Publish(new RequestSent { ID = Guid.NewGuid(), ... })
//I could later subscribe to the event like this:
//eventAggregator.GetEvent<RequestSent>().Subscribe(..)
```

When server responds, the responses are also published to the EventAggregator, so I can subscribe to them:

```
eventAggregator.GetEvent<ResponseFromQueue1>().Subscribe(OnResponseFromQueue1)

eventAggregator.GetEvent<ResponseFromQueue2>().Subscribe(OnResponseFromQueue2)
```

I could also subscribe to RequestSent

**What I need:**

```
private void OnResponseFromQueue1(RequestSent request, ResponseFromQueue1 response)
{
   I need access to both request and respone
}
```

and this would be even better:

```
private void OnResponse(
    RequestSent request, 
    ResponseFromQueue1 response1, 
    ResponseFromQueue2 response2)
{
   //actually, this would simplify implementation of my logic a lot
}
```

Is is possible using RX?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `SelectMany`, assuming you can use something like the ID to associate the request with the responses

```
trigger.SelectMany(requestData => {
  //We need to share this
  var id = Guid.NewGuid();

  //Publish your event
  eventAggregator.Publish(new Request { ID = id, /*...*/ });

  //Start listening for the two responses
  //Grab only the first item matching the IDs
  var left = eventAggregator.GetEvent<ResponseFromQueue1>().First(res => res.ID == id);
  var right = eventAggregator.GetEvent<ResponseFromQueue2>().First(res => res.Id == id);

  //We are done once both values have emitted.
  return left.Zip(right);
}, (request, responses) => {
  /*Here you will have access to the request and an array of the responses*/
});
```

One thing to bear in mind is that this code right now is assuming that `Publish` will return before the responses come back. Since you said this is RabbitMQ that is probably a safe assumption, but something to bear in mind if you do any unit testing with this.

**Edit**

It seems in your scenario you actually would have:

```
//Set up the queue first    
eventAggregator.GetEvent<RequestSent>()
  .SelectMany(requestSent => {
     var id = requestSent.ID;
     var left = eventAggregator.GetEvent<ResponseFromQueue1>().First(res => res.ID == id);
  var right = eventAggregator.GetEvent<ResponseFromQueue2>().First(res => res.ID == id);

  return left.Zip(right);
}, (request, response) => {/**/});

//...Sometime later
eventAggregator.Publish(new Request{});
```

Comment: I'm not sure what trigger is

Comment: It is whatever is initiating your message publication. Could be a button click, or an interval timer.

Comment: ok, actually, it is EventAggregator.GetEvent<RequestSent>(). Request sent which has to be published outside SelectMany...

Comment: Clever solution.  @Liero in Paul's solution, just replace `trigger` with `EventAggregator.GetEvent<RequestSent>()` and change `var id = requestData.Id;` and remove the `Publish()` call he has in there.

Comment: Good call @Brandon. I updated with an example that includes your fix.

Comment: RX are just beautiful , aren't they? :)

Comment: I have extended this question, could you have a look, please? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33239566/use-reactive-extension-to-handle-multiple-responses-in-correct-order @Brandon