# Use reactive extension to handle multiple responses in correct order

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive, reactive-programming

### Situation

I have a system where one request produces two responses. The request and responses have corresponding observables:

```
IObservable<RequestSent> _requests;
IObservable<MainResponseReceived> _mainResponses;
IObservable<SecondResponseReceived> _secondaryResponses;
```

it is guaranteed that `RequestSent` event occurs earlier than `MainResponseReceived` and `SecondaryResponseReceived` but the responses come in random order.

### What I have

Originally I wanted handler that handles both responses, so I zipped the observables:

```
_requests
    .SelectMany(async request =>
    {
        var main = _mainResponses.FirstAsync(m => m.Id == request.Id);
        var secondary = _secondaryResponses.FirstAsync(s => s.Id == request.Id);

        var zippedResponse = main.Zip(secondary, (m, s) => new MainAndSecondaryResponseReceived {
            Request = request,
            Main = m, 
            Secondary = s
        });
        return await zippedResponse.FirstAsync(); ;
    })
    .Subscribe(OnMainAndSecondaryResponseReceived);
```

---

### What I need

Now I need to handle also `MainResponseReceived` without waiting for SecondaryResponseRecieved and it must be guaranteed, that the OnMainResponseRecieved completes before `OnMainAndSecondaryResponseReceived` is called

**How to define the two subscriptions, please?**

Test case 1:

1. `RequestSent` occurs
2. `MainResponseReceived` occurs -> OnMainResponseReceived is called
3. `SecondaryResponseReceive`d occurs -> OnMainAndSecondaryResponseReceived is called

Test case 2:

1. `RequestSent` occurs
2. `SecondaryResponseReceived` occurs
3. `MainResponseReceived occurs` -> OnMainResponseReceived is called -> OnMainAndSecondaryResponseReceived is called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're pretty much on the right track. I would stop mucking around with all the Async stuff - that's just making things complicated.

Try this query:

```
var query =
    _requests
        .SelectMany(request =>
            _mainResponses.Where(m => m.Id == request.Id).Take(1)
                .Do(m => OnMainResponseReceived(m))
                .Zip(
                    _secondaryResponses.Where(s => s.Id == request.Id).Take(1),
                    (m, s) => new MainAndSecondaryResponseReceived()
                    {
                        Request = request,
                        Main = m, 
                        Secondary = s
                    }));

var subscription =
    query.Subscribe(x => OnMainAndSecondaryResponseReceived(x));
```

The `.Do(...)` is the important missing part in your code. It ensures that `OnMainResponseReceived` is called before `OnMainAndSecondaryResponseReceived` no matter if the main or secondary response comes in first.

I tested this with:

```
Subject<RequestSent> _requestsSubject = new Subject<RequestSent>();
Subject<MainResponseReceived> _mainResponsesSubject = new Subject<MainResponseReceived>();
Subject<SecondResponseReceived> _secondaryResponsesSubject = new Subject<SecondResponseReceived>();

IObservable<RequestSent> _requests = _requestsSubject.AsObservable();
IObservable<MainResponseReceived> _mainResponses = _mainResponsesSubject.AsObservable();
IObservable<SecondResponseReceived> _secondaryResponses = _secondaryResponsesSubject.AsObservable();

_requestsSubject.OnNext(new RequestSent() { Id = 42 });
_mainResponsesSubject.OnNext(new MainResponseReceived() { Id = 42 });
_secondaryResponsesSubject.OnNext(new SecondResponseReceived() { Id = 42 });

_requestsSubject.OnNext(new RequestSent() { Id = 99 });
_mainResponsesSubject.OnNext(new MainResponseReceived() { Id = 99 });
_secondaryResponsesSubject.OnNext(new SecondResponseReceived() { Id = 99 });
```

Comment: Just a quick question: Is `_secondaryResponses.Where(...).Take(1)` equivalent to `secondaryResponses.FirstOrDefaultAsync(...)` without await, isn't it?

Comment: @Liero - No, they are not equivalent. The `Where/Take` returns zero or one value. And the `FirstOrDefaultAsync` always returns one value. In fact the `FirstOrDefaultAsync` can be a bit misleading because even if you have `.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x == 1)` you will get a `0` out if the source sequence completes before a `1` is produced.